# Why do I get a Segmentation Fault error after running a vector array

Tags: c++

Possibly a duplicate sorry :/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std;
class CSVReader{
    string fileName;
    string delimeter;

public:
    CSVReader(string filename, string delm = ",") :
            fileName(filename), delimeter(delm)
    { }

    vector<vector<string> > getData();
};

vector<vector<string> > CSVReader::getData(){
    ifstream file(fileName);

    vector<vector<string> > dataList;

    string line = "";
    while (getline(file, line)){
        vector<string> vec;
        boost::algorithm::split(vec, line, boost::is_any_of(delimeter));
        dataList.push_back(vec);
    }
    file.close();

    return dataList;
}
int main(){
    int counter=-1;
    CSVReader reader("ncov_confirmed.csv");
    vector<vector<string> > confirmed = reader.getData();
    reader = CSVReader("ncov_deaths.csv");
    vector<vector<string> > deaths = reader.getData();
    reader = CSVReader("ncov_recovered.csv");
    vector<vector<string> > recovered = reader.getData();
    vector<vector<string> > output;
    output.resize(2592); 
    for (auto &inner : output){
        inner.resize(6);
    }
    for(int j = 0; j<36; j++){
        for(int i = 4; i<40; i++){
            for(int k = 0; k<72; k++){
                counter++;
                output[counter][0]=confirmed[0][i];
                cout << counter << "\t" << output[counter][0] << "\t" << confirmed [0][i] << endl;
            }
        }   
    }
    cout << "end";
}
```

I get segmentation fault after the loop below. I noticed this problem when cout << "end"; doesnt output anything. It outputs what I programmed in the for loop and then boom. Segmentation fault.

```
    for(int j = 0; j<36; j++){
        for(int i = 4; i<40; i++){
            for(int k = 0; k<72; k++){
                counter++;
                output[counter][0]=confirmed[0][i];
                cout << counter << "\t" << output[counter][0] << "\t" << confirmed [0][i] << endl;
            }
        }   
    }
```

Can someone explain to me why there is the segmentation fault error and how to solve it? Any help is appreciated. Ps. I get random segmentation fault codes first time I compile it gives me 82302 then 82334 and now it is 82557. Why?

Comment: Think about the maximum size of `counter`. If I'm not mistaken it goes up to `36*40*72 - 1 = 103679`.

Comment: What if `confirmed[0]` doesn't have between `4` and `40` elements?

Comment: my ```counter``` only counts up to 2592

Comment: And yet you increment `counter` `103680` times.

Comment: @anonym ... probably because you get the segfault as soon as counter reaches 2592, which happens to be exactly the size of `output`.

Comment: Magic numbers are suspicious. Can you explain why `2592`, `6`, `36`, `4`, `40`, and `72` appear in your code and why they are indisputably correct? (c.f. [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging))

Comment: And as for @Some Programmer dude, my confirmed vector is ```confirmed[73][40]```

Comment: And what is 36? You do that 36 times over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I found out my error tho. I created a vector output[2592][6], and my counter is up to 103680. Its like I put 2592 apples into a box and now I'm trying to find the 103680th apple. Impossible right? So the correct code should be just:

```
    for(int i = 4; i<40; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k<72; k++){
            counter++;
            output[counter][0]=confirmed[0][i];
            //cout << counter << "\t" << output[counter][0] << "\t" << confirmed [0][i] << endl;
        }
    }
```